# Magento 2: After update to PHP 7 checkout.phtml not loaded / no success message

Tags: onepage-checkout, php-7

i upgraded from PHP 5.6.x to 7.0.4. The shop itself is working fine, but after the onepage checkout on the success page (where normally the file /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml is loaded, this file seems not to be loaded.
There is no success message, just the message "click here to get an account" which normally appears after the success message.
I activated path hints, but there is no success.phtml loaded...
The confirmation email is sent and the order is in the system correctly...
Just the text / messages are missing.
I deleted all cache (by hand via ftp), also full page cache...

The template hints are showing the following files:

/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/skiptarget.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/button.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/messages.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/section-config.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/customer-data.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/templates/javascript.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-msrp/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/registration.phtml

Has anyone a hint or an idea?
(Running on nginx)
Thank you.